# Terraform wants to replace Google compute engine if its start/stop scheduler is modified

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, cloud, google-compute-engine

First of all, I am surprised that I have found very few resources on Google that mention this issue with Terraform.
This is an essential feature for optimizing the cost of cloud instances though, so I'm probably missing out on a few things, thanks for your tips and ideas!

I want to create an instance and manage its start and stop daily, programmatically.
The resource "google_compute_resource_policy" seems to meet my use case. However, when I change the stop or start time, Terraform plans to destroy and recreate the instance... which I absolutely don't want!

The resource "google_compute_resource_policy" is attached to the instance via the argument [resource_policies](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#resource_policies) where it is specified: "Modifying this list will cause the instance to recreate."

I don't understand why Terraform handles this simple update so badly. It is true that it is not possible to update a scheduler, whereas it is perfectly possible to detach it manually from the instance, then to destroy it before recreating it with the new stop/start schedule and the attach to the instance again.

Is there a workaround without going through a null resource to run a gcloud script to do these steps?

I tried to add an "ignore_changes" lifecycle on the "resource_policies" argument of my instance, Terraform no longer wants to destroy my instance, but it gives me the following error:

```
Error when reading or editing ResourcePolicy: googleapi: Error 400: The resource_policy resource 'projects/my-project-id/regions/europe-west1/resourcePolicies/my-instance-schedule' is already being used by 'projects/my-project-id/zones/europe-west1-b/instances/my-instance', resourceInUseByAnotherResource"
```

Here is my Terraform code

```
resource "google_compute_resource_policy" "instance_schedule" {
  name = "my-instance-schedule"
  region = var.region
  description = "Start and stop instance"

  instance_schedule_policy {
    vm_start_schedule {
      schedule = var.vm_start_schedule
    }
    vm_stop_schedule {
      schedule = var.vm_stop_schedule
    }
    time_zone = "Europe/Paris"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "my-instance" {

  // ******** This is my attempted workaround ********
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [resource_policies]
  }

  name = "my-instance"
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  zone = "${var.region}-b"

  allow_stopping_for_update = true

  resource_policies = [
    google_compute_resource_policy.instance_schedule.id
  ]

  boot_disk {
    device_name = local.ref_name
    initialize_params {
      image = var.boot_disk_image
      type = var.disk_type
      size = var.disk_size
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = data.google_compute_network.default.name
    access_config {
      nat_ip = google_compute_address.static.address
    }
  }
}
```

If it can be useful, here is what the `terraform apply` returns

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  - destroy
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # google_compute_resource_policy.instance_schedule must be replaced
-/+ resource "google_compute_resource_policy" "instance_schedule" {
      ~ id          = "projects/my-project-id/regions/europe-west1/resourcePolicies/my-instance-schedule" -> (known after apply)
        name        = "my-instance-schedule"
      ~ project     = "my-project-id" -> (known after apply)
      ~ region      = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/regions/europe-west1" -> "europe-west1"
      ~ self_link   = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/regions/europe-west1/resourcePolicies/my-instance-schedule" -> (known after apply)
        # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)

      ~ instance_schedule_policy {
            # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)

          ~ vm_start_schedule {
              ~ schedule = "0 9 * * *" -> "0 8 * * *" # forces replacement
            }

            # (1 unchanged block hidden)
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions in workspace "prd"?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

google_compute_resource_policy.instance_schedule: Destroying... [id=projects/my-project-id/regions/europe-west1/resourcePolicies/my-instance-schedule]

Error: Error when reading or editing ResourcePolicy: googleapi: Error 400: The resource_policy resource 'projects/my-project-id/regions/europe-west1/resourcePolicies/my-instance-schedule' is already being used by 'projects/my-project-id/zones/europe-west1-b/instances/my-instance', resourceInUseByAnotherResource
```

**NB:** I am working with Terraform 0.14.7 and I am using google provider version 3.76.0

Answer (score 1):

An instance inside GCP can be power off without destroy it with the module [google_compute_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance) using the argument [desired_status](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#desired_status), keep in mind that if you are creating the instance for the first time this argument needs to be on “RUNNING”. This module can be used as the following.

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "test"
  machine_type = "f1-micro"
  zone         = "us-west1-a"
  desired_status = "RUNNING"
}
```

You can also modify your “main.tf” file if you need to stop the VM first and then started creating a [dependency in terraform](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/dependencies#manage-explicit-dependencies) with depends_on.

As you can see in the following comment, the service account will be created but the key will be assigned until the first sentence is done.

```
resource "google_service_account" "service_account" { 
   account_id = "terraform-test" 
   display_name = "Service Account"
}

resource "google_service_account_key" "mykey" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.service_account.id 
  public_key_type = "TYPE_X509_PEM_FILE" 
  depends_on = [google_service_account.service_account]
}
```

If the first component already exists, terraform only deploys the dependent.

Comment: Thanks for your proposition @Nadia Espinosa
However, this does not seem to solve my problem. Adding the "desired_status" argument on "RUNNING" value indeed generates the same behavior of the instance (its destruction) when the "google_compute_resource_policy" resource is modified

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem with snapshot policy.

I controlled resource policy creation using a flag input variable and using count. For the first time, I created policy resource using flag as 'true'. When I want to change schedule time, I change the flag as 'false' and apply the plan. This will detach the resource.

I then make flag as 'true' again and apply the plan with new time.

This worked for me for snapshot policy. Hope it could solve yours too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the "resourceInUseByAnotherResource" error by adding the following lifecycle to the google_compute_resource_policy resource:

```
lifecycle {
  create_before_destroy = true
}
```

Also, this requires to have a unique name with each change, otherwise, the new resource can't be created, because the resource with the same name already exists. So I appended a random ID to the end of the schedule name:

```
resource "random_pet" "schedule" {
  keepers = {
    start_schedule = "${var.vm_start_schedule}"
    stop_schedule  = "${var.vm_stop_schedule}"
  }
}
...
resource "google_compute_resource_policy" "schedule" {
  name = "schedule-${random_pet.schedule.id}"
  ...
  lifecycle {
     create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```